# Eclipse java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, eclipse, derby

my project is giving the following error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.jerby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver
Here is my CreateDatabase code:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
//jj
public class CreateDB {
    private static final String DRIVER = "org.apache.jerby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    private static final String JDBC_URL = "jdbc:derby:test;create=true";
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException{
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(JDBC_URL);
        connection.createStatement().execute("Create table channels");
        connection.createStatement().execute("Inserting values");
        System.out.println("Database created, records inserted.");
    }
}
```

Comment: The driver is not on your java class path. Are you using an IDE?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using Eclipse, you can right click on your project and within the context menu select: "Build Path" -> "Configure Build Path..."

Click on the Libraries tab and then click the "Add JARs..." button and add the jar file that contains your embedded driver.

Answer (score 0):

You can go to the properties file for that project and manually add that class to the classpath. Alternatively if you're using one of many IDE's such as NetBeans or IntelliJ, you can do so in the project properties.